# Photoshop 2022 incompatibility with GPU driver and DirectX

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu, adobe-photoshop

I have a AMD HD 7470 on my a bit old pc, with Core i3-3220 and Win10 x64 OS 20H. I have a problem when I run Ps 2022 on it. When I install last version of video card driver from AMD website (last update 2015), I get the following error

[image]

and when I update video card driver from device manager (last update 2021), I get the following error

[image]

I have tried by enabling `Direct Play` under `Legacy Components` in `Turn Windows Features on or Off` but wasn't helpful.

Comment: The 7470 is 10 years old at this point. DX12 is supported on a fairly large number of old and new GPUs and I'm sure you could get  a 2 GB card fairly inexpensively even in this GPU "shortage". Windows 10 support ends on October 14, 2025 so sooner or later you'll be upgrading your entire system anyways.

Comment: my wonder is that why in one setting it says that it support Oppencl and DX12 but not in other one

Comment: Different components report information in different ways. Both of your GPU and iGPU (Intel HD Graphics 2500) are 10 years old at this point and Adobe probably doesn't care enough to get their error message perfect. You'll notice that your second screenshot is not detecting the 7470 but rather the basic MS Render driver. Your driver update made your 7470 undetectable by Adobe so this is your reward for using old hardware. These kinds discrepancies happen all the time, by the way... especially with older hardware.

Comment: Presumably you can still install Photoshop, right? You'll just have certain features disabled https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-cc-gpu-card-faq.html#Whichfeaturesleveragethegraphicsprocessor

Comment: Yes, Of course.

Answer (score 1):

Ps 2022 requires DX 12 & 1.5GB GPU RAM minimum. That card can only do DX 11 & only has 1GB RAM. It looks like when you allow Win itself to update the driver, it switches to the on-board GPU [which can borrow system RAM], which is also too old for 2022. Like many of us… you're stuck with 2021.

That AMD GPU was one of many abandoned at the release of Windows 10. The general rule for the two last available drivers is to stick to the final release, 15.7.1 unless you have issues; then try the beta 16.2.1
In this particular case, neither driver will give you DX 12 or the extra RAM.

You've reached End of Life with that machine, I'm afraid.

Comment: You are right that Ps 22 needs DX 12 but why in my pc it passes DX requirement by showing green checkmark?

Comment: That's when it's using the GPU chipset in the CPU itself. Neither GPU is up to minimum spec, but each for a different reason.

Comment: I don't think so. My VGA cable is connected to Video Card port and CPU integrated graphic VGA port is not connected to any cable. Also 1GB is VRam on video card but shared VRAM is 4GB. (Note that CPU integrated GPU has less than 512MB capacity.)